# html5 number input type step attribute multiplying number with 100

Tags: php, mysql, html

Here is the simple code:

```
 Amount: <input type='number' step="0.01" min="1" max="500" name='pr_amount' id='pr_amount' /><br>
```

This form is made with PHP to insert data in MYSQL Database. 
INPUT 1.50 OUTPUT in the database 150.00

How to solve this? Do I need to use $pr_amount/100 type of code at the php coding section or is there any other way. without step="0.01" it's not taking the decimal part in points or the cent value of dollar.

**PHP Part:** payment.inc.php

```
      if (isset($_POST['pr_amount'], $_POST['pr_processor'],$_POST['pr_comment'])) {
// Sanitize and validate the data passed in
$pr_amount = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pr_amount', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$pr_processor = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pr_processor', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pr_comment = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pr_comment', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user_id']);

// for checking minimum payout allowed
         if ($pr_amount < 1) {
    // If it's not, something really odd has happened
    $error_msg_payout .= '<p class="error">Minimum Payout is $1.00, for INR withdraw Minimum payout is Rs.100</p>';
}
   if(empty($pr_amount || $pr_comment)) {
  $error_msg_payout .= '<p class="error">User must input all field</p>';
   }

// checking if pr amount is above the available balance
$stmt_balance = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT current_balance FROM client WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt_balance->bind_param('i', $user_id);
    $stmt_balance->execute();
    $stmt_balance->store_result();
if($stmt_balance < $pr_amount){
    // If it's not, something really odd has happened
    $error_msg_payout .= '<p class="error">Payment request amount is greater than the available balance.</p>';
}
 $stmt_balance->close();

//-------For checking pr comment validity
     if (strlen($pr_comment) > 150) {
    // If it's not, something really odd has happened
    $error_msg_payout .= '<p class="error">Payment instruction should be within 150 charecters</p>';
}
if (!ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '',$pr_comment))) {
$error_msg_payout .= '<p class="error">Payment Instruction Include disallowed charecters</p>';
}

if (empty($error_msg_payout)) {

    // Insert the new account into the database 
    if ($insert_stmt_payout = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO payment (user_id,pr_amount,pr_comment,pr_processor) 
SELECT ?, ?, ?, pr_processor FROM paymentlist WHERE pr_processor = ?")) {
        $insert_stmt_payout->bind_param('idss', $user_id,$pr_amount,$pr_comment,$pr_processor);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt_payout->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=AddPayment failure: INSERT');
            exit();
        }
    }
    //---deducting balance after succesful request       
    $stmt_deduct = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE client SET current_balance = (current_balance-?) WHERE user_id = ?");
    $stmt_deduct->bind_param('di', $pr_amount,$user_id);
    $stmt_deduct->execute();
    if (! $stmt_deduct->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=AddPayment failure: INSERT AMOUNT');
            exit();
        }
        $stmt_deduct->close();          
    header('Location: ./payment.php');
    exit();
}
```

}

**HTML PART:** payment.php

```
<form method="post" name="payment_request" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
        Add Request:
        <?php
         $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT pr_processor FROM paymentlist '); 
         $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
         $stmt->bind_result($pr_processor);
         $stmt->store_result();
         echo "<select name='pr_processor'>";
         while($stmt->fetch()) {
         echo "<option value='" . $pr_processor . "'>" . $pr_processor . "</option>";
          }
         $stmt->close();
         echo "</select>";
         ?> <br>
         Amount: <input type='number' min="1" max="500" name='pr_amount' id='pr_amount' step='0.01' value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' /><br>
          Payment Instruction: <input type='text' name='pr_comment' id='pr_comment' /><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Payout Request" name="addpayment" />
    </form>
```

**Note:** If I don't use step, then it takes only integer and output of the input are perfectly ok. But I required the input in money value with decimal point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your html code on https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number and it showed the correct number value after submitting the data.

Are you processing $pr_amount before adding it to database. Please post the complete contents of your php file.

Comment: I updated the php part with full code, yes I am processing the $pr_amount before adding it to the database. Please take a look. Thank you

Comment: You need to add the FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION flag to your filter_input function call. So your filter should be: `$pr_amount = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pr_amount', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);`. See this link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_number_float.asp

Comment: Just one question at the " if (!ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '',$pr_comment))) " section is possible allow user to input numbers & "." & ":" & ","@" charecters? ( I mean colon, comma, fullstop & @ sign)

Comment: You are welcome. The ctype_alpha only allows alphabets. '.', '&' are not allowed. You can use ctype_print function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-print.php

Comment: Sorry but I have done the full testing now, there is a problem with deducting balance. if $pr_amount = 1.00 on current_balance it shows it deducted 2.00 why is such?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are making this calculation ?

Comment: Hi it already provided in the php section" //---deducting balance after succesful request"

Comment: Hi. This code does not seem to be correct: `empty($pr_amount || $pr_comment)`. You should replace it with: `empty($pr_amount) || empty($pr_comment)`

Comment: Hello I did that, but that doesn't solve the problem yet.:(

Comment: Whats the value of $pr_amount just before you subtract it from the balance?. Add this line before the "deducting balance after succesful request" comment: `die($pr_amount);`

Comment: die shows 1.06 if I add payment request with 1.06. But its deducting 2.12 from current balance

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `$stmt_deduct->execute();` twice, so it is deducting the amount twice. Just remove the first call: `$stmt_deduct->execute();`

Comment: on 1st call it just simply executing. but the second one "if (! $stmt_deduct->execute())" part here its checking what if the sql command got executed or not.  Then how can I sort it out?  How to set this part?

Comment: Yes, I did remove the 1st part and it worked! I have used this type of if(!stmt->excute()) checking code all over my coding template then I guess I have to remove it for all. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type='number' min="1" max="500" name='pr_amount' id='pr_amount' step='0.01' value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' />
```

Comment: I applied your code, but no luck still 1.50 out in database is 150.00